# DataTables - Invalid JSON Response Query

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've created a page using a .csv file (comma delimited file) as the data source, but when I load the page an Invalid JSON response error is returned.
When I check Network > XHR I can't see any error information and nothing is displayed under the Response tab. However, when I click on the OK button to dismiss the error message, all the data from the .csv file is displayed under the Response tab.

The same issue results whether I host the files locally or on my webserver.

Could this be an issue with a configuration in the https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js file? I've provided the relevant header code I've used for reference below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<style type="text/css" class="init"></style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mrgs').DataTable( {
        "ajax": 'mydata.csv'
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CSV data is not JSON - they are completely different structures. DataTables expects JSON-structured data not CSV-structured data.  Also, where is your `<table>` element and where is the mapping from your data source to table columns?

Comment: There are various examples [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html) - do they help to clarify what you need to do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply andrewjames. There is nothing wrong with the table columns mapping:

Comment: <div class="mrgs-html">
        <table id="mrgs" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Qtr</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Forename(s)</th>
                    <th>SpseName</th>
                    <th>District</th>
                    <th>Volume</th>
                    <th>Page</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

Comment: The issue must be that a .csv file is not accepted.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show the new information (the HTML in your comment). But just to clarify: The mapping I referred to is needed in the DataTables definition. It appears to be missing. (And, yes, DataTables expects JSON when handling an Ajax response).

Comment: It looks like the csv file needs to be converted to a json array and saved as a txt file if I've understood correctly.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: There are several different ways to provide data to your DataTable. One way is to do what you are describing - but your browser will probably block your Ajax request with a CORS error if you try using `"ajax": 'mydata.txt'`. Did you look at the examples I linked to in my second comment?

Comment: And [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/index.html) are more ways, if you don't want to use Ajax. For example, using a JavaScript variable (an array of arrays, or an array of objects), or even simply hard-coded in the HTML.

Comment: Converting the csv file to json allowed the data to be displayed and the data to be filtered and sorted both locally hosted and on the webserver. No ajax issue was encountered. Is that likely to be a problem that other users could encounter when trying to load the pages?

Comment: I just noticed your comment/question "_Is that likely to be a problem...?_". Small tip: If you want to ping a commenter specifically, you can use the at-sign with a user ID (@andrewjames). First of all - I am glad you have a solution - that is great! Regarding the CORS issue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local). I am surprised your local Ajax file URL worked.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and your assistance as well, andrewjames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preprocess your csv to be in the array of object values format DataTable wants.

Here is the complete solution ready to plug into your page

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="mrgs" class="table"></table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "./data.csv",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(csv) {
        let allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        let headers = allTextLines[0].split(',').map(e => e.trim());
        let lines = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
            let line = allTextLines[i].split(',') // take the comma separated line, turn into an array
                .reduce((b, a, index) => { // b is the accumulator, a is the iteration value
                    b[headers[index].toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')] = a.trim(); // set the object property and value
                    return b; // return the accumulator for our next iteration
                }, {});
        if (Object.keys(line).length === headers.length) lines.push(line)            }
        // now fix headers to be object/value pairs
        headers = headers.map((e) => ({
            title: e,
            data: e.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')
        }))
        // console.log(headers)
        //  console.log(lines)
        $('#mrgs').DataTable({
            columns: headers,
            data: lines
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let csv = `Type,Qtr,Year,Surname,Forenames,SpseName,District,Volume,Page 
  Marriages,Dec,1837,JAMES,Ann,,Mansfield,15,942 
  Marriages,Dec,1839,Karlton,Diana,,Mansfield,15,1017 
  Marriages,Dec,1841,Mepham,Elizabeth,,Mansfield,15,994 
  Marriages,Sep,1842,CASPIAN,Sophia,,Mansfield,15,617 
  Marriages,Dec,1842,Kennedy,Mark,,Mansfield,15,957
  Marriages,Dec,1843,Crampus,Elizabeth,,Mansfield,15,1034 
  Marriages,Mar,1846,Dalton,Paulina,,Mansfield,15,741 
  Marriages,Dec,1846,JAMIESON,William,,Mansfield,15,1031 
  Marriages,Dec,1848,Rodon,Reuben,,Mansfield,15,1096 
  Marriages,Mar,1849,PHILBERT,Reuben,,Mansfield,15,703 
  Marriages,Dec,1849,STARKEY,Thos,,Mansfield,15,1092 
  Marriages,Jun,1850,Porter,John,,Mansfield,15,843`
  let allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  let headers = allTextLines[0].split(',').map(e => e.trim());
  let lines = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
    let line = allTextLines[i].split(',') // take the comma separated line, turn into an array
      .reduce((b, a, index) => { // b is the accumulator, a is the iteration value
        b[headers[index].toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')] = a.trim(); // set the object property and value
        return b; // return the accumulator for our next iteration
      }, {});
    if (Object.keys(line).length === headers.length) lines.push(line)
  }
  // now fix headers to be object/value pairs
  headers = headers.map((e) => ({
    title: e,
    data: e.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')
  }))
  // console.log(headers)
  //  console.log(lines)
  $('#mrgs').DataTable({
    columns: headers,
    data: lines
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="mrgs" class="table"></table>
```

Comment: Thanke for your reply Kinglish. It would definitely save time if I could avoid having to convert the files. However, when I replaced the document ready function code with your code and edited the url  line to point to the csv file only the table header from the <table> code is displayed. No data is displayed, no search field, no sort facility, no show x number of entries dropdown. What am I overlooking?

Comment: I updated my answer, the code and added an example snippet

Comment: I can see the code snippet works, but when I replace the code with:

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mrgs').DataTable( {

let csv = `First name, Last name, Address, City, State, Zip
John,Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075
Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
Stephen,Tyler,7452 Terrace At the Plaza road,SomeTown, SD, 91234,
Blankman,,SomeTown, SD, 00298`

Comment: let allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
let headers = allTextLines[0].split(',').map(e => e.trim());
let lines = [];
for (let i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
  lines.push(allTextLines[i].split(',').map(e => e.trim()))
}

    $('#mrgs').DataTable({
      columns: headers,
      data: lines
    });
  });
})

Comment: No data is returned as previously.

Comment: What I noticed when I converted the csv file manually is that I had to wrap the output json text with  {    "data":  <converted json text>    } and then the converted csv data displayed. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I updated my example. There were a couple things that needed fixing. I commented some of the code. Pls check and if this answers your question, please accept the answer and consider an upvote for the effort. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Kinglish. When I run your code using the let csv = statement and when I store the data in test.csv the four rows of data are displayed without any error as expected. However, when I use the same code and replace test.csv with my test data that has 174 rows including the header row I get the error: "DataTables warning: table id=mrgs - Requested unknown parameter 'qtr' for row 173, column 1."

Comment: I click OK to dismiss the error and the same error is presented again. I click OK again and then the data is displayed with a blank first row. I can't see anything wrong with the data and I've no idea why a blank first row is being returned. I suspect whatever is causing the initial blank row might be the issue.

Comment: Can you share your data source? I can't comment on what I cant see.

Comment: Either post a link to your data, or update your question with a sample of the data

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "mydata.csv",
  }).done(function(csv) {
  let allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  let headers = allTextLines[0].split(',').map(e => e.trim());
  let lines = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
    let line = allTextLines[i].split(',') // take the comma separated line, turn into an array
      .reduce((b, a, index) => { // b is the accumulator, a is the iteration value
        b[headers[index].toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')] = a.trim(); // set the object property and value

Comment: return b; // return the accumulator for our next iteration
      }, {});
    lines.push(line)
  }

Comment: // now fix headers to be object/value pairs
  headers = headers.map((e) => ({
    title: e,
    data: e.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')
  }))
  // console.log(headers)
  //  console.log(lines)
  $('#mrgs').DataTable({
    columns: headers,
    data: lines
  });
});
})

Comment: no. not that. Please share the data. the csv. is there a link to it? Or maybe you can copy a bunch `and add it to your question`. thanks

Comment: Seriously, can you copy the first 5 or six lines of it and put it in your question? Or share a link? I am leaving soon and want to wrap this up

Comment: No data is initially returned if I add 3 additional columns of data to your data. Here is some sample data:

Comment: Type,Qtr,Year,Surname,Forenames,SpseName,District,Volume,Page
Marriages,Dec,1837,JAMES,Ann,,Mansfield,15,942
Marriages,Dec,1839,Karlton,Diana,,Mansfield,15,1017
Marriages,Dec,1841,Mepham,Elizabeth,,Mansfield,15,994
Marriages,Sep,1842,CASPIAN,Sophia,,Mansfield,15,617
Marriages,Dec,1842,Kennedy,Mark,,Mansfield,15,957

Comment: Marriages,Dec,1843,Crampus,Elizabeth,,Mansfield,15,1034
Marriages,Mar,1846,Dalton,Paulina,,Mansfield,15,741
Marriages,Dec,1846,JAMIESON,William,,Mansfield,15,1031
Marriages,Dec,1848,Rodon,Reuben,,Mansfield,15,1096
Marriages,Mar,1849,PHILBERT,Reuben,,Mansfield,15,703
Marriages,Dec,1849,STARKEY,Thos,,Mansfield,15,1092
Marriages,Jun,1850,Porter,John,,Mansfield,15,843

Comment: Thx - I'll add that to the answer

Comment: can you check your source - are those separated by line breaks? When I copy and paste your comment it all comes out on one line, which would change my solution. Please check

Comment: Yes, each line of data is separated by a line break.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to parse a separate .csv file, not parse embedded comma delimited text in the php file. The text included is a tiny sample of the data. The intended csv files will include many thousands of rows of data and many more columns. Hence the reason for intending to use the $(document).ready(function() { $.ajax({ url: "mydata.csv", }).done(function(csv) { method. Is this simply not possible?

Comment: Of course, the snippet is just a demo of the functionality. I updated the answer to have the complete solution. You just need to change the URL where the csv is located. I tested it on my own server.

Comment: I've worked out that if the .csv file is saved in CSV UTF-8 (Comma-delimted) (.csv) format the error:  "DataTables warning: table id=mrgs - Requested unknown parameter 'qtr' for row 173, column 1." is displayed. The error always relates to the last row of data irrespective of the number of records. If the file is saved in Comma-separated Values (.csv) format the table displays without error.

Comment: Ok, we're getting somewhere! I just added this line to the answer `if (line.length === headers.length) lines.push(line)` which will prevent the table from accepting rows that aren't completely filled (which appears to be the error you're getting). Can you try that?

Comment: Thanks for your patience, Kinglish. Replacing lines.push(line) with if (line.length === headers.length) lines.push(line) produces error alert but instead of the returned rows of data the following message is displayed in the table: No data available in table.

Comment: Ha, my bad. Forgot `line` was an object - fixed in answer and snippet with this : `if (Object.keys(line).length === headers.length) lines.push(line)`

Comment: That fixed the issue. :) Thank you kindly for all your assistance, Kinglsih

Comment: @ridgedale - Alright! That's great news. How about selecting this as the answer and giving it an upvote as well for the effort. Cheers

Comment: I was trying to work how to upvote and accpet the answer. It is quite frankly not obvious. As I now understand the person raising the question has to click the up-arrow (to the top left of the answer) to upvote the answer and click on the tick below the arrows to accept the answer. I hope that is correct. Many thanks again.

Comment: You did it. Thanks! I also upvoted your question as it's somewhat unique and required a few layers of solving